# Toggle `fn` key via keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

Has anyone figured out a way to toggle the function keys on and off via key board shortcut on a macbook? Even remap the `fn` key to work more like the caps lock where you do not need to hold it down. It would be really nice to just remap the caps lock to toggle function keys, instead of using it for capitalizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/ (KeyRemap4Macbook) to set a new function key.

*If you're on a macOS Sierra beta, this won't work. Risks with beta software...*